# Grant "create schema" ON database to a user?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, role

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 and have to to grant "create schema" ON database to a user.

How can I do that?

Comment: -> [The fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It's more simple than I thought.

```
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE db TO user;
```

Comment: is there documentation for this anywhere?  The postgres docs are pretty scant on info about what the various GRANTs do....